# Cypress Runner Blocked by An Extension

Tags: google-chrome, cypress

I have been trying to get Cypress to run tests for about a week now, but I simply can't get past this chrome error talking about an extension blocking the cypress runner (if I run it in other browsers it also fails, although the other browsers simply time out and don't mention an extension - even so I'm not convinced it's a chrome issue).  It loads the page fine but breaks on the first action, in this case clicking a login button from a portal.

[image]

I have tried restarting computer, reinstalling chrome, reinstalling cypress, reinstalling dotnet, re-cloning my entire repo containing cypress (3 times at least), and clearing web data (10 times at least).  Other articles online have mentioned setting `chromeWebSecurity = false` in cypress.json but that has been the default for me since the beginning and this issue persists.

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Your question lacks debugging details, can you provide a cut-down version of the repo?

Comment: it's a git repo and it's set up like C:/repos/repo/AngularApp/tests/ and in that folder you have fixtures, plugins, integration, and support folders - all my tests live in integration folder

Comment: What part of the code are you looking for?  Cypress is just a small part of the repo.  And like I said, the page loads fine, so I suspect that the tests are configured correctly and that the problem lies in the web request in some way.

Comment: I think we'd certainly like to see the test, but this problem feels like the app needs to be run to understand what goes wrong, so if your repo is on Github...

Comment: I mean, a blank screenshot is just a bit too minimal. There's already one close vote, and I presume you want to sort it out?